# Write a negative time with PHPExcel - XLS

Tags: php, date, phpexcel

I'm doing a class that receives a complete worksheet, reduces the amount of information, and answers another worksheet, in that worksheet that has a field where there can be negative time (-H: i), the function:

```
$file ['AH42'] = '-0:21';

$hdE = \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($file['AH42'], 'HH:i'));
```

Give me back:

`$ hdE = '23: 39'`, when it should return `'-0:21'`.

How can I do this ?

Make PHPexcel return a negative time without calculating from `00:00`

Comment: Use `-hh:mm` as the format mask.... but don't confuse MS Excel date format masks with PHP date format masks

Comment: But whenever you ask something like `Make PHPexcel return a negative time without calculating from 00:00`, always ask how you would do it in MS Excel first.... [Microsoft do offer a couple of solutions here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/182247/negative-date-and-time-value-are-displayed-as-pound-signs-in-excel)

Comment: In Excel I have the format [H]: MM Time, this field means that hours are missing to complete a certain period, then it may be positive or it may be negative, it will depend on how many hours are left or how many hours are left over (PS: it is in LibreOffice ).

Comment: Same principle still applies; look at the linked page from Microsoft explaining how to format negative times.... those methods should work in both MS Excel and Open/Libre Office.... Open/LibreOffice itself will allow negative times

Answer (score 1):

Maybe move minus sign to format string?

```
$file ['AH42'] = '0:21'
$hdE = \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($file['AH42'], '-HH:i'));
```

Comment: This works, but this field can be negative as it can also be positive and I have no control over the spreadsheet that comes for me to modify

Answer (score -1):

## Don't use PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat

PHPExcel v1.6 `PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString` function does, is call `sprintf([predefinedFormat], $value)`, or returns the results of `date()`. None of the predefined formats can handle negative time. Further, the format argument you gave `-HH:i` isn't that function's accepted list, so it just returns the value.

PHPExcel v1.8 does allow for highly complex custom number formatting options, but still does not handle negatives in dates or times.

See: [PHPExcel github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Style/NumberFormat.php) for v1.8 and [cmsws phpexcel docs](http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/phpexcel/Documentation/API/__filesource/fsource_PHPExcel_Style__PHPExcelStyleNumberFormat.php.html#a40) for v1.6

## Just format it yourself

Note, you can't just call [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) as that function does, as php `date()` does not support negative timestamps. So you'll have to manually account for the sign.

```
$time = $file['AH42'];
$hdE = ($time < 0) ? '-' : '';
$hdE = date('H:i', (1 * abs($time)));
```

While this does technically mean you're operating on an Epoch timestamp on 1 Jan 1970, the time will still be accurate (that's how Excel works).